# What would be the best Regex to match a 14 digit merchant ID that contains both all caps characters and numbers - Always starts with an "A"

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out what the best regex is to match merchant IDs from Amazon.  All merchant IDs are 14 characters long, contain both numbers and characters (capitalized), and always begin with an "A".  Here is one example: A1BXXQBIGBE6UH

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be:

```
/A[A-Z0-9]{13}/
```